# Convert image URL into a File - Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a basic question and I'd appreciate your help guys.

I want to convert image URL (**not Local URL**) into a File - Javascript

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
let file = new window.File(['https://ps.w.org/wp-mail-smtp/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=1785565'], { type: "image/png" })
```

Error: `Failed to construct 'File': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That link is to a png file, but you are constructing a file of type "image/jpeg". Also, that isn't even valid JS, you open an array but don't close it.

Comment: @LukeRamsden I fixed it. Thanks for your tip. Do you know about this

Comment: This works fine in Chrome

Comment: @Niladri I use Chrome and get error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'File': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.`